# HTML form doesn't want to send an image

Tags: python, django, forms, multipartform-data, fastapi

I have a complicated task and for now I don't know reason why things don't work correctly.

So I have 2 services - my Django main server and OCR service. OCR service is built with FastAPI and only takes image, processes it and returns response as JSON with data from image. That's how my fastapi file looks like:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Request

import celery_launch
from cleaning_folders import cleaning_folder
from config import save_img_from_form


f_app = FastAPI()

def save_img_from_form(image):
    ts = time.time() * 1000
    digit = random.randint(0, 9)
    file_name = "img_{digit}_{ts}.jpg".format(digit=digit, ts=ts)
    with open(os.path.join('temp_img', file_name), 'wb') as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(image.file, buffer)
    return buffer

@f_app.post("/api/ocr")
async def send_request(image: UploadFile = File(default='Any', media_type='multipart/form-data')):
    buffer = save_img_from_form(image)

    response = celery_launch.ocr_process(
            selected_town='Templates/Chernomorsk',
            raw_img_path=buffer.name,
            selected_billing_type=1
        )

        json_response = response.get()

        cleaning_folder('temp_img')
        return json_response
```

so save_img_from_form() gets an image object from request and saves it to the disk for next processing. Then celery runs and does all OCR process and then returns a dict.

So when I use Swagger UI as interactive API testing service, it all works, so in Swagger UI I can load my image through html input and then click the button to run my endpoint. And then I get right JSON as response. I also checked the network activity (ctrl+shift+I in Chrome) and in network action, which is linked to my endpoint I see lots of stuff about my request and also form data (image ofc).

But the question is in another. I need to load an image at my Django server and then using requests library send request with this file to FastAPI service. But here I faced with lots of troubles. I have such an html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'send_ocr_form' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{pk}}">
        <input type="file" id="ocr_image" name="ocr_image" accept=".jpg, .jpeg"><br>
        <button type="submit">Recognize</button>
</form>
```

Hidden field with name="pk" is needed for some service stuff. So for loading an image I have a field with name="ocr_image".

My view for this form is:

```
def send_ocr_bill_form(request):
    image = request.FILES['ocr_image'].temporary_file_path()

    ocr_response = send_ocr_bill(image=image)
    files = {'file': open(image, 'rb')}
    ocr_response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5005/api/ocr', files=files)
    print(ocr_response.json())

    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/accounts/profile_page/'))
```

It's not the full functionality of this view, it just not ended because of current trouble.

So when I send my form with image FastAPI uses default='Any' as an image variable, so that means that there are no files in request. And when I check network I also don't see 'form data' block in my request. So it seems like I don't send image. But in my view I can easily get and print an object from request.FILES, see its name and temporary path, so that means that I load image and send it in my request.

And interesting fact. When I delete my file input and leave only csrf token and pk hidden input and then submit form, in my request in network I can see form data and then get my "pk" in a view. But when I return file input, form data block disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many hours spent to solve the issue and answer was so easy.
Well, my fail was with requests library.
Let's look at my FastAPI's endpoint first string:

```
async def send_request(image: UploadFile = File(default='Any', media_type='multipart/form-data')):
```

So i define 'image' as an UploadFile object, and of course my endpoint waits for a file in request, but when I send image in a Django view I do this:

```
files = {'file': open(image, 'rb')}
ocr_response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5005/api/ocr', files=files)
```

So in 'files' variable I also use 'file' key to assign image to it.
And all I needed to change is:

```
files = {'image': open(image, 'rb')}
ocr_response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5005/api/ocr', files=files)
```

Now when FastAPI endpoint gets a request, it takes image argument from the right place and then I can do all stuff with it.